# How to select the method at compilation time?

Tags: c++, templates

I remember reading some article using new C++ features to implement the selection at compiler time but cannot figure out how to do it. For example, I have a method doing the following

```
template<class T>
void foo()
{
   if (std::is_abstract<T>::value)
         do something;
   else
         do others.
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the enable_if struct, I believe

Comment: Unless one side of the `if`/`else` causes a compilation error, this is a perfectly fine solution (the unused side will get recognized as unreachable dead code by any decent compiler). Otherwise, you'll need SFINAE; there's too much to say about it so I won't even bother. Search for it on Google or SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If both of your branches compile, the above code is actually OK and will do the selection at compile time: there will be one branch the compiler will detect as being dead and never use. When optimizing no self-respecting compiler will use a branch.

Especially when the branches may not compile depending on the type, you could use `std::enable_if` to conditionally make overloads available:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_abstract<T>::value>::type foo()
{
    do something
}
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_abstract<T>::value>::type foo()
{
    do other
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Compile time decision making is usually done through overload selection.

```
void foo_impl(std::true_type) {
    do something;
}
void foo_impl(std::false_type) {
    do others.
}

template<class T>
void foo()
{
   foo_impl(std::is_abstract<T>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `std::is_abstract` utility is an example of a [*type trait*](http://erdani.com/publications/traits.html), and I have like to follow the classical selector idiom:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template<bool>
struct algorithm_selector {
  static void implementation() {
    std::cout<<"I am using the default implementation"<<std::endl;
  }
};

template<>
struct algorithm_selector<true> {
  static void implementation() {
    std::cout<<"I am using the 'custom' implementation"<<std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
void foo() {
  algorithm_selector<std::is_abstract<T>::value>::implementation();
}

struct ABC { virtual void bar() const = 0; };
struct Derived : ABC { };
struct Blah {};

int main() {
  foo<ABC>();
  foo<Derived>();
  foo<Blah>();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled as (gcc 4.8.1) `g++ example.cpp -std=c++11` yields the output:

```
I am using the 'custom' implementation
I am using the 'custom' implementation
I am using the default implementation
```

What I like about it is that it goes beyond the *enable_if* rationale (at least conceptually): it provides me with and idiom which I can use to select arbitrary *strategies* at compile time. It is just a matter of preference, probably, but to me the idiom is rock solid. Also, check out the *Policy* patterns described in [Andrei Alexandrescu's book](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/); they are related to this flexibility in design powered by compile-time power.